# Нарушается структура страницы

Tags: php, разметка

При переходе в информацию об сотруднике, смещается блок в котором отражены ФИО, ссылка "Выход", привилегия, и информация об новых зарегистрированных пользователей. На других страницах ничего не сдвигается. Прошу помочь. Ниже предоставляю код страницы:

```html
<?
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
session_start();
echo "<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf8mb4_general_ci'>
<link href='css/general.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery_1.5.2.js'></script>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body id = 'body'>
<div id='left_panel'>
<div class=''loader'></div>
</div>";
    include('config/function.php');
    include('config/connect.php');
    include('config/class_query.php');
    include('config/var.php');
    include('config/class_js.php');
    $query_db = new query_db();
    $db_connect = new db_connect(); // Подключение к классу connect
    $user_num_day = $query_db->reg_user_site_day();

    if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'login' )
        {
            include( 'html/login.php' ); //Авторизация пользователя
        }

    if (isset ($_SESSION['auth']))
        {
            echo "
            <input type='checkbox' id='side-checkbox' />
            <div class='side-panel'>
            <label class='side-button-2' for='side-checkbox'>+</label>    
            <div class='side-title'>Система управления баллами</div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=add_client'> Добавить клиента </a></div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=service_user'> Операции с клиентом </a></div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=look_user'> Журнал клиента </a></div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=tec_support'> Тех.поддержка </a></div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=worker_plan'> Журнал добавления баллов </a></div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=operation_worker'> Добавление или редактирования сотрудника </a></div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=return_buy'> Возврат покупки </a></div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=setting_ball_platform'> Настройка платформы </a></div>
            <div  class = 'a_gen_link'><a href='index.php?page=version_site'> Версия сайта </a></div>
            
            </div>
            <div class='side-button-1-wr'>
            <label class='side-button-1' for='side-checkbox'>
            <div class='side-b side-open'>≡</div>
            </label>
            </div>
            ";
        }
        else
        {
            include( 'html/login.php' );
        }
?>

  <div id="worker_window">

    <?      
    if (isset( $_GET[ 'page' ]) && isset ($_SESSION['auth']))
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'add_client') {
                include( 'html/add_client.php');
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'add_ball') {
                include( 'html/add_ball.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'use_ball') {
                include( 'html/use_ball.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'look_user') {
                include( 'html/look_user.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'proceeds') {
                include( 'html/proceeds.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'tec_support') {
                include( 'html/tec_support.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'worker_plan') {
                //Информация об выполнении плана сотрудникам
                include( 'html/worker_plan.php');
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'edit_user') {
                include( 'html/edit_user.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'service_user' ) {
                include( 'html/service_user.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'profile' ) {
                include( 'html/user_worker_profiles.php');
                //Профиль сотрудника
                
            }
            if (preg_match('/^\d+$/i', $_GET[ 'page' ])) {

                $_SESSION['edit_user_id'] = $_GET[ 'page' ];
                include( 'html/edit_profile_user.php' );
                
            }
            if ($_GET['page'] == 'operation_worker' && $_SESSION['level_privilege'] == admin)
            {
                include( 'html/add_and_edit_profile_worker.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'return_buy' ) {
                include( 'html/return_buy.php' );
            }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'version_site' ) {
                    include( 'html/version_site.php' );
                }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'visitors_reg_user' ) {
                    include( 'html/visitors_reg_user.php' ); 
                }
            if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'setting_ball_platform' && $_SESSION['level_privilege'] == admin) {
                        include( 'html/setting_ball_platform.php' );
                    }
        }
    ?>

  </div>

  <div id='right_blok'>
    <div id='login_blok'>

      <?
if (isset($_SESSION['auth']))
        {
            echo "<div class='login_auth'> | <a href=?exit>Выход</a></div>";
            echo "<div class='login_auth'> <a href='index.php?page=profile'>" .$_SESSION['FIO_worker']. " </a></div>";
            echo "<div class='login_auth'> Уровень доступа - $level_privilege </div>";
            echo "</div>
<div id='visitors_reg_user'> <a href='index.php?page=visitors_reg_user'> Новые регистрации на сайте ($user_num_day) </a><div>
</div>
";

            if (isset($_GET['exit']))
                {
                    session_destroy();
?>
        <script>
          location.replace("http://vhost146665.ispsite.ru/");
        </script>

        <?
                    exit;
                }
        }
?>
    </div>

  </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Если мы нажимаем на ФИО сотрудника (на картинке это строка в правом верхнем углу) то загружается информация из if ( $_GET[ 'page' ] == 'profile' ) {
include( 'html/user_worker_profiles.php');
//Профиль сотрудника

Вот скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поэтому не надо смешивать php и html.. Ищите ошибку в тегах, где-то что-то не там закрывается

Comment: Проблему решил. Была ошибка в одном из методов. Дописав к таблице echo "" проблема решилась.

Comment: Проблему решил. Была ошибка в одном из методов. Дописав к таблице echo</tbody></table>  проблема решилась.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Была ошибка в одном из методов. Дописав к таблице echo "" проблема решилась.